# Regression Loop by category

Tags: r, for-loop, foreach, linear-regression

I have a data set that has multiple engines and I want to create a for loop function to run a linear regression for each engine and to extract the coefficients of each regression. So I want the first regression to run across the six weeks with engine= Google and then the second one to run across the six weeks with engine =Bing, etc. A sample of the data set looks like this:

```
Engine  Wk   Imp   Clicks  lnSpend  Actions CPA
google  1   100302  15791   10998    31     354.79
google  2   23893   4734    2866     16     179.18
google  3   318       16    37.83    11     3.44
google  4   7992    1980    1704.81  27     63.14
google  5   13206   3292    2732.13  26     105.08
google  6   10888   2966    2293.86  22     104.27
bing    1   23536   1808    1028.95  3      342.98
bing    2   86873   7196    2740.28  14     195.73
bing    3   54654   4398    1786.96  13     137.46
bing    4   45553   3353    1860.47  13     143.11
bing    5   41254   3322    1811.80  13     139.37
bing    6   38305   3117    1501.01  19     79.00
```

The regression equation is `actions~ spend` and this would remain constant across all the engines.

This is the code that I have so far:

```
for(i in unique(mydata$engine)) 
  {
  reg<- append(reg, lm(mydata$Actions~ mydata$lnspend, data=mydata[mydata$engine== i,]))
}
summary(reg)
```

However, when I do that, the regression runs on the full data set combining all of the engines together.

I also tried using a by function. The code that I have for that is

```
reg<- by(mydata$engine, function(mydata) lm(Actions~ lnspend, data=mydata))
sapply(reg, coef)
```

When I run that I get the following error:

> "Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax)"

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: You could try `lapply(split(df, df$Engine), function(x) coef(lm(Actions ~ lnSpend, data = x)))` in base R

Comment: Yes, this works, thank you! Do you know how I can extract the coefficients of the regression for each one? Normally when I extract coefficients, I do "constc<-summary(reg)$coefficients[1, 1]" but I'm not sure how I can do that in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
mydata=data.table(mydata)
mydata[,as.list(lm(Actions~lnSpend)$coeff),by=Engine]

    Engine (Intercept)     lnSpend
1: google   17.632263 0.001318611
2:   bing    4.735979 0.004341699
```

Comment: I tried installing the package "data.frame" but I get the error that it is not available for R version 3.2.0. Are there any other packages that can extract the coefficients from the regression into a table?

Comment: it should be "data.table", not "data.frame". And it is used only for grouping,  which you can also do in {dplyr} or in base R

Answer (score 1):

You can also make it work by adjusting your first for loop a bit:

```
Engine <- c('g','g','g','g','g','g','b','b','b','b','b','b')
Actions <- c(31,16,11,27,26,22,3,14,13,13,13,19)
lnSpend <- c(10998,2866,37.83,1704.81,2732,2293,1028,2740,1786,1860,1811,1501)
df <- data.frame(Engine,Actions,lnSpend)
reg <- c()
for (eng in unique(Engine)){
  m <- lm(Actions~ lnSpend, data = df[which(df$Engine == eng),])
  reg <- append(reg, m$coeff)
}
reg
# > reg
# (Intercept)      lnSpend  (Intercept)      lnSpend 
# 17.632629162  0.001318568  4.734059476  0.004344177
```

Comment: When I adjust the loop to your code, it still combines all of the engines together and runs only one regression.

Comment: I just edited it so that it only pulls out the coefficients. I believe the original version worked, but  both lm results were just pasted together.

Answer (score 0):

Your for/loop should work. You just did not filter your dependent and independent variables in for/loop by engine type, so R takes the full dataset:

Consider either explicitly referencing the subset filter in each variable:

```
for(i in unique(mydata$engine)) 
  {
  reg<- append(reg, lm(mydata$Actions[mydata$engine== i] ~ mydata$lnspend[mydata$engine== i],
               data=mydata[mydata$engine== i,]))
}
```

Or leave anonymously so data argument dictates the structure:

```
for(i in unique(mydata$engine)) 
  {
  reg<- append(reg, lm(Actions ~ lnspend,
               data=mydata[mydata$engine== i,]))
}
summary(reg)
```